# AZ vm create can't attach to existing vnet correctly

Tags: azure-cli

I am attempting to create vm's from an image in one Tenant/subscription to another Tenant/subscription and when I try to specify the existing vnet name and subnet, it creates a new vnet with the same name in a different resource group. It then puts the nic into a subnet I don't want. I am a novice attempting this so I am not sure if its the order of the parameters or what.

This is what I attempted;

```
az vm create 
--resource-group rg-z-a2fp-wfx-vm-test 
--name $VMname 
--image "/subscriptions/$ID/resourceGroups/rg-flexrx-dev-vm/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/WFX_GI_Gallery/images/WFX-GI-19gen/versions/0.0.1" 
--admin-username $user 
--public-ip-address "" 
--size Standard_ds2_v2 
--vnet-name vnet-z-a2fp-flexrxvm-n-001 
--subnet sn-z-a2fp-flexrxvm-vn1 
--nsg "" 
--generate-ssh-keys
```

What happens is that it creates a new vnet with a duplicate name in the resource group `rg-z-a2fp-wfx-vm-test` and I want it to use the already established vnet with the specified existing subnet in my resource group `rg-z-a2fp-flexrx-n-001`.

Answer (score 0):

If the vnet is in a separate RG, you'll need to specify the full resource ID of the subnet instead of the subnet name.
eg `--subnet /subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnetname>/subnets/<subnetname>`

Edited to reflect the correct answer.

RBAC wise, you'll need, at minimum, permissions pretty similar to the ones needed for Private Endpoints in the vnet. If you have contributor or vm administrator for the destination resource group, that works too.

Comment: I attempted adding that after the --vnet-name and received an error.                         
 incorrect usage: --subnet ID | --subnet NAME --vnet-name NAME                                              Entered after --vnet-name /subscriptions/<guid of second tenant>/resourceGroups/rg-z-a2fp-flexrx-n-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-z-a2fp-flexrxvm-n-001

Comment: This did it for me, I just ran into an issue with permissions in a resoucre group. I did not use the --vnet-name becuase there were multiple subnets. Instead I used it after --subnet and that got me where i needed.

Comment: You're right! I remembered the pitfall but totally misremembered the command argument.